# Travel to Dublin, Ireland from UK on a Tier 2 ICT long term staff partner visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I have an Indian passport and currently am in UK on a Tier 2 ICT long term staff partner visa valid up to January, 2020. My question is whether I need an additional visa to visit Dublin, Ireland to meet my sister who is on a student visa in Dublin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need a visa for the Republic of Ireland. The visa type is 'C' and when you apply, choose Visit (Family/Friend) visa.

You may have heard that some people with Indian passports can visit Ireland with certain UK visas, and vice versa, but it only applies if you have a short stay visa like a tourist visa, not if you have a long-stay visa.

Details [here](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-short-family) from the Irish Nationalisation and Immigration Service.

Comment: Also having a long term UK visa is very good in your favour for getting your Irish visa accepted